Contour integration with 4 or more branch points
Is there a notable example, or any for that matter, of commutator contour integration of multivalued function with $4$ or more branch points?
Example of the case with 2 branch points used for integral representation of Kummer Function:

NIST Handbook of Mathematical Functions, 13.4
I wrote a modest post on the topic, and would benefit from a good example to demonstrate the construction of the contour and the calculation.
